# How to parse column data to rows in google sheets with query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unpivot, google-query-language

I have the follwoing spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mq4REmOqrfQiyCJ8-IIuLDZvzmh_I1lvAqZgOPQCQ74/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Source data]

I need to re-organize the info as follows.

[image: expected_result]

I have tried using the following:

```
=query({query(source!A:K,"select A,D");query(source!A:K,"select A,E");query(source!A:K,"select A,F")},"where Col1 is not NULL order by Col1")
```

which gives me results where semana, horas and pago are all mixed together. See it below.

[image: my_result]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be a query? General formula will do.

Comment: Ir does not have to be a query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [labels](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) for setting the right column header and also select the right columns including that extra column representing the week. Here is an example for the first week, for retrieving the rest just append the rest weeks as you did in the example you provided:

```
=query(source!A:K,"select A,'2020-20',D,E where A is not NULL label A 'Nombre', D 'horas',E'pago','2020-20' 'semana'")
```

Demonstration:
[image]

To query the rest of years you just need to nest the queries in a bigger query and **select** the right columns of each week. For example, the relevant columns for the week `2020-20` would be `A` (the one containing the names which is comon for all weeks), `D` and `E` as these are the columns containing that week's information. For `2020-21` it would be columns `A`, `F` and `G` and so on. Also, note that you will only need to add the labels on the first query as you only want the headers `Nombre`,`semana`,`horas` and `pago` on the first row.

Here is an example with the first two weeks:

```
=query({query(source!A:K,"select A,'2020-20',D,E where A is not NULL label A 'Nombre', D 'horas',E'pago','2020-20' 'semana'");query(source!A:K,"select A,'2020-21',F,G where A is not NULL")})
```

Comment: This answer works for one week only, I tried nested queries for the other week numbers, but it repeats the first set of values only.  =query({query(source!A:K,"select A,'2020-20',D,E where A is not NULL label A 'Nombre', D 'horas',E'pago','2020-20' 'semana'");query(source!A:K,"select A,'2020-21',D,E where A is not NULL label A 'Nombre', D 'horas',E'pago','2020-21' 'semana'")})  https://static.md/487f7cf45b98b3cc3405fdc69f80b74b.png

Comment: Hi ! I have updated my answer to explain you how to expand my query to cover the rest of the weeks. Basically the issue in the query you just showed me is that for week 2020-21 you are selecting the same columns from the original source (```A```,```D``` and ```E```) instead of selecting the right columns for week 2020-21 which would be ```A```,```F``` and ```G```. Let me know if you have any doubts regarding this and if my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it :D

Comment: Yes, it should have been pretty obvious, now I'm doing a super-nested query for something like 30 weeks. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you :D